# fix vertical scrollbar position to 2nd row in div(cshtml)?

Tags: html, razor, scrollbar

I have a div with a scroll bar which displays 15 months with 3 of the min each row, When the page loads I want to fix the scroll bar position to 2nd row as shown in my screenshot.As in the scroll bar should to be fixed to the position shown in my screenshot as opposed to top of the div.The reason for this requirement is we are displaying previous 3 months, but the user should see the current month when the page loads. I hope I have made it clear [image]

I am using

```
<div id="key_dates" style ="overflow:scroll;width:960px;height:500px">
```

Can you guys please help?

Thanks,
Adarsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JavaScript for this:

```
<!-- 
     Place this script before closing </body> tag so that
     DOM (HTML elements tree) is already built when the script is running 
-->
<script>
// create a closure to not pollute global scope
!function () {
  // cache reference to keyDates element
  var keyDates = document.getElementById('key_dates');
  // set scroll to the height of one row
  keyDates.scrollTop = 150; // substitute `150` with height of one row
} ();
<script>
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop) is the documentation of element.scrollTop

If you are using jQuery, you do it like this (and [here](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) are the docs);

```
<script>
$('#key_dates').scrollTop( 150 );
</script>
```

An example with jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/gryzzly/CjdwX/

Comment: Adjusting based on height seems more appropriate for me as I dont really have control over rows. But when I added this peice of code in jquery $('#key_dates').scrollTop( 150 ); the scrollbar position didnt seem to change at all. Anything I might have missed here?

Comment: notice that we change `scrollTop` of the parent, the container, the element that has `overflow:scroll` applied to it

Comment: Hmm, I am guessing somewhere a page reload is happenning again, trying to figure out the problem

Comment: Got it :) I put this in the right place now, It worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems I can't demonstrate this properly with jsfiddle, but [here is a sample of code](http://jsfiddle.net/PfLS3/2/) which works if you test it in a browser. Using anchors on each row, we can anchor the window to a specified location either using href or the url.

For example, if you implemented this code at `www.address.tld/calendar`, to show row two, you'd enter `www.address.tld/calendar#row2`.

You can use only an anchor on row two, and you could place it either statically or programmatically depending on your needs. It's a pretty straight forward solution, but some people don't like the hash and anchor name being in the url. It doesn't bother me.

Comment: You can demonstrate it like this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/PfLS3/2/show/light/#row2

Comment: @gryzzly Perfect! Thanks for the pointer. Also, great answer above.